# Converting a 3D array to a 2D array in Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

Suppose I have a 4x2x2 array such that

```
val(:,:,1) =

    1.0000   18.2190
    1.0000   15.4650
   12.0223   76.2841
   64.1669  104.7139

val(:,:,2) =

    1.0000   18.2190
   18.2190   18.6414
   11.5436   74.6475
   74.7046  110.4268
```

I am trying to "flatten" this 3D array into a 2D array so that it looks something like this

```
val(:,1) = 

    1.0000   
    18.2190
    1.0000   
    15.4650
    12.0223   
    76.2841
    64.1669
    104.7139
```

Is there a shorthand method for doing this so I can avoid using for-loops?

Comment: `reshape` can do that.  `reshape(val,[8,2])`.

Comment: I am trying to flatten "row-wise", unfortunately reshape does not do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a combination of `permute()` to rearrange your dimensions and then `reshape()` towards the desired format:

```
tmp = permute(val, [3, 2, 1]);
tmp2 = reshape(tmp, [size(tmp, 1), size(tmp, 2) * size(tmp, 3)]).'

tmp2 =

    1.0000    1.0000
   18.2190   18.2190
    1.0000   18.2190
   15.4650   18.6414
   12.0223   11.5436
   76.2841   74.6475
   64.1669   74.7046
  104.7139  110.4268
```

Or as a one-liner:

```matlab
tmp2 = reshape(permute(val, [3, 2, 1]), [size(val, 3), size(tmp, 2) * size(val, 1)]).'
```

Answer (score 4):

You can also use pagetranspose which makes it very short:

```
reshape(pagetranspose(val),[],1)
```

Answer (score 3):

The transpose step can be removed by rearranging `val`, so that the linear indexing order is already correct going into `reshape`. Which is rearranging so that the order is dimension 2, 1, then 3.

```matlab
reshape(permute(val, [2, 1, 3]), [size(val,2)*size(val,1), size(val,3)])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reshape( v, [], 1 )` to reshape a matrix into a single column with however many rows are required. Doing this to each slice of you `val` array and concatenating them is one way to achieve what you want:

```
[reshape(val(:,:,1).', [], 1), reshape(val(:,:,2).', [], 1)]
```

The transpose `.'` operators here are so that the reshaping is essentially row-major as you want rather than column-major as it actually operates.